# Different answers using product and quotient rule for differentiation

Tags: calculus

I am trying to differentiate this:

$$y = \frac{x}{e^x}$$

**via Quotient Rule**:

$$y' = \frac{(e^x*1) - (x*e^x)}{e^{2x}}$$

$$ = \frac{e^x(1-x)}{e^{2x}}$$

$$ = \frac{(1-x)}{e^x}$$

**via Product rule:**

$$y = x*e^{-x}$$ so

$$ y' = x*e^{-x} + e^{-x}$$

$$ = e^{-x} * (x+1) $$

$$ = \frac{(x+1)}{e^x}$$
Obviously I'm making a mistake somewhere. Where is it?

Comment: just a chain rule error in the product rule computation

Comment: Product rule: y' =-xe^{-x} +e^{-x}, first minus sign is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you differentiate $e^{-x}$ in the product rule version, you didn't put a minus sign in front. It should differentiate to $-e^{-x}$.

---

**Edit:**

$$\begin{align}y &= x\cdot e^{-x}\\\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{d}{dx}(x)\cdot e^{-x}+x\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x})\\&=1\cdot e^{-x}-xe^{-x}\\&=\frac{1-x}{e^{-x}}\end{align}$$

Comment: you mean I *didn't put a minus sign in front right?

Comment: @Jwan622 does my edit help clear it up?

Comment: what's the rule here that turns the derivative of e^-x to -e^-x?

Comment: @Jwan622 u-substitution: u=-x, du=-1dx; d/du(e^u) => (e^u)du => (-e^-x)dx

Comment: @Jwan622 let $y=-x$. Then $$\frac{d(e^{-x})}{dx}=\underbrace{\frac{d(e^y)}{dx}=\frac{d(e^y)}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}}_{\text{by chain rule}}=e^y\times\frac{d(-x)}{dx}=e^{y}\times(-1)=-e^{-x}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^{-x} = -e^{-x}$$

Comment: I thought the derivative of e^x with respect to x was e^x?

Comment: @Jwan622 It is.  But to evaluate $e^{-x}$ you have to use the chain rule.  Let $y=-x$.  Then $$\frac{d(e^y)}{dx} = \frac{d(e^y)}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} = e^y(-1) = -e^{-x}$$

Comment: @Jwan622 but in this question, it is not the derivative of $e^x$, it is the derivative of $e^{-x}$ that you are required to compute.

Comment: how does one do that? I thought it would still follow the rule no?

Answer (score 1):

Heren you made a mistake :

$$y' = xe^{-x} + e^{-x}$$

It should be :

$$y' = -xe^{-x} + e^{-x}$$

$$y' = e^{-x}(1-x)=\frac {1-x} {e^x}$$